# htaccess and 301 Redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used to have the following URL structure for my video website:

```
http://domain.com/v/VIDEO_CODE/VIDEO_SLUG
```

I have now changed it to:

```
http://domain.com/VIDEO_SLUG
```

**My .htaccess looks like this:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ ./index.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]

# Old URLs
Redirect 301 /v/sNzpNC2acrA/tightrope-canyon http://domain.com/tightrope-canyon
```

I have a big list of 301 redirects so that the old video links on Twitter etc still work.

**My issue**, When I visit:

```
http://domain.com/v/sNzpNC2acrA/tightrope-canyon
```

it redirects to:

```
http://domain.com/tightrope-canyon?slug=v/sNzpNC2acrA/tightrope-canyon
```

which loads fine, but I want it to stop putting the `?slug=`... (previous URL) bit on the end of the URL.

Comment: There is a RedirectMatch directive, so don't need to "have a big list of 301 redirects."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rewrite rule (using mod_rewrite) to redirect OLD URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^v/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

The `?` at the end will get rid of old query string.

If you want to use `Redirect` directive... then use `RedirectMatch` instead of hundreds of hardcoded `Redirect 301 ...`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/v/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1?
```

You .htaccess with such rule may look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^v/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ ./index.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This worked great thank you! Had to adjust the $1 for $2 for the slug to transfer rather than the code.

Comment: @alexcroox Bit odd -- can you please show me the final rule .. as I do not understand where `$2` may came from if you were copied without modifying anything (if you made changes, then maybe yes).

Comment: sorry I forgot I changed the regex for the code section to allow additional chars and must of put a rogue $ in there!